# Creating viber account on tablet

Tags: viber-messenger

So I get myself android tablet last nite and wanted to create viber account.  I put my cell phone number down,  and never received code on my phone. I still have flip phone, not smart phone. Could that be reason? I would be very interested in this product and I would appreciate if someone could help me.

Another question would be is it possible to create viber account without phone number?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use voice callback option. See [this](https://support.viber.com/customer/portal/articles/1379211-how-do-i-use-automatic-callback-#.VnRXCq8wgxO).